# How to add a number of items in to a "new category" or an "existent category"

Tags: usability, design-patterns, lists, categories

I have a list where the user can choose multiple items, and than he can press a button that will "add the selected items to a category". But I want the user to be able to add the items to:

a) A new category
b) An existing category

My first idea was show a screen to choose option A or B, and than the next screen will ask the category name or list all existing categories. But I'm not sure that is the ideal way.

I tried to search about this, but I don't know what keywords to use.

Comment: What information is displayed when listing existing categories (just a name?) and what information must be provided by the user when creating a new category?

Comment: a) The category name and the sun of itens inside this cat;

Comment: b) When create a new cat, just a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My online email client does the same thing as pictured. And another does the same.
[image]

So you are in a right way.

Comment: I liked your idea a lot, but how does it work with 100+ items?

If I expand the box to 200px and add a scroll and a serach field maybe can fix my problem. what do you think?

Comment: This is a good solution. Since the user only need enter a name when creating a new category, you could even include a text input and an 'add' button directly at the top of this menu without having to send the user off somewhere else.

Comment: For 100+ items you can use a type ahead field. The field can also allow the user to type in a new item.

Comment: @MaxAndriani, I'd do exactly what you've said: scroll and search.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to have in each line of the list the possibility to "add to category.." or to "create new category".

Spotify uses something like that and I think it works fine. The only issue for me is that is only visible on mouse over and that could bring accessibility problems.

But, like I said, for me was intuitive. There's a screen shot. Hope it helps!!

[image]

Comment: This idea is very nice to use in single tasks. But I think it is not very usefull when the user need to interact with 30 or 40 items because he need to do it for each item.